# Why are my event handlers not being attached to elements created in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a five star rating system.  There are five star icons.  When an icon is clicked, I want to change the value of an input to whichever star is clicked(e.g. if the fourth star is clicked, the input will have a value of 4).  My problem is that the click method that I apply to the newly created icon does not work at all.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShoeLace1291/9mLzLsw7/) to demonstrate.

html

```
<div class="rating" style="float: none;clear: both;">
  <noscript>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" title="1 Star"> 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" title="2 Stars"> 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" title="3 Stars"> 3
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" title="4 Stars"> 4
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" title="5 Stars"> 5
    </label>
  </noscript>
</div>
<input type="text" name="stars" value="" id="stars">
```

Javascript

```
 $element = $('.rating');
  $element.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var occurrence = i + 1;
    var newStar = $('<i class="fa fa-star-o" title="' + occurrence + ' stars" data-occurrence="' + occurrence + '"></i>');
    newStar.on('click', function() {
      $('#stars').val(occurrence + ' stars given.');
    });
    $element.append(newStar);
  }
  $element.each(function() {
    var _parent = $(this);
    var originalStars = _parent.html();
    $(_parent).on('mouseover', 'i[class*="fa-star"]', function() {
      var starOccurrence = $(this).prevAll().andSelf().length;
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(_parent).html(originalStars);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Replacing the `innerHTML` gets rid of the internal state of all elements, including event listeners. Don't do that.

Comment: ^ that, you keep getting the HTML as a string, and reinserting it, loosing all the event handlers and associated data for each element.

Comment: So how else can I add elements without removing the event listeners?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: Use event delegation - there's 100s of examples on SO.

Comment: use event delegation if you must replace the html...although there are simple enough ways to do this with class changes and not replacing html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems. 
Mentioned in the comments, don't replace the inner html, just remove/add classes to reset the stars.

```
.mouseout(function() {
    $('i').removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
  });
```

Second problem is you need to grab the occurrence value from the data attribute, and not the overwritten occurrence variable.

```
$('#stars').val($(this).data('occurrence') + ' stars given.');
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9mLzLsw7/2/

Comment: The first problem isn't an actual problem.  The problem is within the for loop.  The elements have to be created first before those removeClass and addClass can work.

Comment: You are creating the elements though, and the class adding/removing works in my fiddle.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you are saying.  And the issue wasn't the delegation at all like the others said. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Going a bit further, you can (1) avoid the need for `data-occurrence` by exploiting jQuery's `.index()`, (2) delegate 'click' handing to the `.rating` container, (3) append the `<i>...</i>` string directly, without first wrapping in jQuery. I would write something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9mLzLsw7/5/).